# Show that whether or not an arbitrary Turing machine ever executes a particular one of its instructions is unsolvable

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

Show that whether or not an arbitrary Turing machine ever executes a particular one of its instructions is unsolvable. (This is the same as the problem of detecting unreachable code in a program.)

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: I have no idea how to prove it formally, can you help me, @HenningMakholm ? See what I have until now "If we would have a way to say if some instruction will be executed, we could find a solution for the halting problem. Basically we will ask if the problem execute the “return” statement, or other statement that indicate the halt, but we can’t resolve the halting problem, so this machine cannot exist."

Comment: x @chgsilva: That seems to be a complete proof.

Comment: Yes-the critical instruction is "transition to the stopping state."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we would have a way to say if some instruction will be executed, we could find a solution for the halting problem. Basically we will ask if the problem execute the “return” statement, or other statement that indicate the halt, but we can’t resolve the halting problem, so this machine cannot exist.